# Automatically transfer information from Dictionary to Anki

Tags: python, dictionary, anki

I’m learning language and I have to learn lots of words. In order to learn the words efficiently I use Anki Software, which is an open-source flashcard software for spaced repetition. My Problem is that, there are thousands of words, which I should manually search in dictionary and enter in Anki. Is there any way to speed up this process? Can I develop a software, which takes the words from a list and search the meaning in the dictionary and put the information in Anki automatically? If there is a way, how and with which programming language?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [Anki Manual](https://docs.ankiweb.net/#/importing):

> *«**Anki can import text files**, packaged Anki decks created by the export feature, Mnemosyne 2.0 .db files, and SuperMemo .xml files. To import a file, click the File menu and then “Import”.»*

Then you just need to code a program which generates your import files as needed. For example, generate text files with your words and its meanings, separated by tabulators.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great idea. But still something is not clear for me. How can I generate the import files? Which program can search in dictionary and save the results for example in .xml format?

Comment: If you don't have another flashcard software (e.g. Mnemosyne, SuperMemo, ...) the easy way is to use a text file.  You can programmatically create that file, for example with Python's `csv` module (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html if you know Python).

Also you can create it in a spreadsheet and then save it as .tsv file (tab-separated values).  Try creating you first Anki Note in Anki itself, then export to a .tsv file and open it in your favorite spreadsheet software.

Add your data by Copy & Paste into your sheet and finally, save your .tsv file to import it back to Anki.